# Place to hire Solidity dev for 2-3 day job?

Tags: dapps, etherscan, hardhat

Not sure whether this question is appropriate here.  Please redirect me if not.  I'm looking for a recommended way to hire a solidity developer for this weekend.

I would like to have a script that can execute a smart contract on Ethereum given the contract address, the method address and input parameters. I don't care about UI (I'm a developer myself); I just want a general purpose tool that I can use to execute generic contracts on Ethereum mainnet and ropsten. The build would preferably be done in Hardhat, for me to learn from and add to later.

Where would you look for such a hire?

Comment: https://github.com/Madeindreams

Comment: @MadeInDreams Could you say a bit more?  Not sure what you had in mind when you sent the link.  Are you sharing a repo that already has this functionality?

Comment: Not as one package ready to go but I can put one together with generic bases to deploy, run task and test. All the bases could be there with maybe a few example along to get familiar. Maybe take a look at this one. https://github.com/MadeInDreams-Team/intro-to-mid

Comment: If you can't use Etherscan (not verified) and/or don't bother to have the ABI, you can use https://evmconnector.dev/

Comment: @LauriPeltonen that looks interesting.  Thanks for sharing.  I will try it out.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know you can do what you're asking for in Etherscan?

If you go to a contract address, in the "Contract" tab, in "Read contract" and "Write contract" you can read and write transactions for the contract.

Comment: Thank you!  The contract I'm most interested in playing with does not have its source code on Etherscan, so those options do not appear.  I do know the method signature I'd like to try.

Comment: Ah, I see. This is quite a basic script to make in Hardhat. I think a fair price would be $50 (for a script that allows you to execute a certain function with certain parameters on certain contract) though you might be able to find cheaper, but also you know, some developers' time is worth more than that. I suggest you try on Upwork or the jobs channel on this discord: https://discord.gg/WKeHH5BZ . My advice is to try to present as much details as possible so there will be no misunderstandings. You can also ask for instructions on how to "fork the mainnet", you might find it useful, google it.

Comment: I came to that realization (Hardhat) after sitting on this for 12hrs. I realized that I don't actually need a smart contract for this.  I can write a simple Hardhat task that will interact with the deployed contract through ether.js.  Hardhat allows me to fork the chain and play with it locally first, so I can test my script safely.  Thanks for your suggestions :-)